# Upload project zipped to github and unzip after uploading

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, github, open-source

I have opensource project needed to be uploaded to GitHub when I upload it unzipped it takes a lot of time to do so 
so I'm asking for a way to upload it zipped and unzip it after uploading it 
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have no choice but to do a regular `git push`. This will be as fast as uploading a zipped archive, maybe even faster.

Try using `ssh` and not `https` for your remote connection.

Comment: I'm skeptical about "maybe even faster", but it won't be much worse. One benefit of push over .zips, though, is that it'll avoid uploading duplicate objects you might have in and out of packs too. If you run `git repack -a -d` locally first then git will pack all of your (reachable) objects into a single pack file for upload, which you can see in .git/objects/packs if you'd like to convince yourself this is a reasonably compressed format. It might do that anyway as part of the push lead-in but it's never completely clear to me.

Comment: Git compresses objects anyway, so using a zipped file won't be faster.

Comment: It worked but I don't know if using the shell is the reason or using git repack -a -d 
thanks all ♥ :)